# VS 11 does not pay attention to install location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've download VS 11 Developer preview. I do not have sufficient disk space in my C drive, so I entered "`E:\Program Files\Visual Studio 11\`" as the install location and the installer continues, but after a while, my `C:` drive goes out of disk space and I get the following error in the log file:

> (vs_professionalcore) failed: Error: 1601 ErrorMessage: Out of disk
>   space -- Volume: 'C:'; required space: 606,561 KB; available space:
>   178,516 KB.  Free some disk space and retry.

Note that no files gets copied to my E: drive during the installation process. What's the solution?

Comment: I hope you've reported this to Microsoft so they can fix it?

Comment: I've already reported this issue to Microsoft. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690485/visual-studio-11-developer-preview-installer-seems-to-ignore-the-installation-location

Answer (score 8):

This isn't unique to VS 2011. All versions of Visual Studio (at least all the .NET flavors I have used since 2002) have strong dependencies that can only installed onto the C: drive.

These dependencies can be stuff like the .NET 4.5 and various runtime components. The IDE itself is all that can be placed on another drive.

You usually see this in the installer where it will show that after changing the drive letter still large parts of the C: drive will be used.

I decided to fire up a VM and see what the difference was between C drive install and E drive install on VS 2010 Ultimate. As you can see the difference was only ~2GB with the bulk being on the C drive still as I stated above.

[image: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate C Drive Full Install]
[Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate C Drive Full Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsYHC.png)
[image: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate E Drive Full Install]
[Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate E Drive Full Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtcMK.png)

Comment: If you are right, why does the installer initialize with no error message regarding lack of disk space in all of involving partitions? In VS 2010, if we choose to install the software in another partition and there is no sufficiemt disk space in "C:" drive, the installer will throw an error and it will not continue.

Comment: @Harry.B It is a Developer Preview (close to Alpha) so there are issues to be expected, such as missing or incorrect error messages. I was merely pointing out that needing large amounts of C: drive space has always been the case with VS and is unlikely to change (you were concerned about getting it installed purely on the E drive).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a solution here.  This sounds like a simple bug in the installer.  The only real option is to file a bug on Visual Studio Connect to ensure it's fixed for RTM

- http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Note: This is a preview release so quality is not that of RTM.  It's certainly a case I would expect to be fixed for RTM though.  When I worked in Visual Studio QA in particular often installed to non-default locations.

Comment: Yes, the nature of Preview versions is to have some bugs, but changing install location is one of the most basic tasks of an installer.

Comment: @Harry.B I'm not disagreeing with that.

Comment: They are using Wix to create the installer in this version, new code new bugs